# when application crashes , app languages change

Tags: android, locale

my application supports arabic and english languages , if application language is arabic and application crashes for any reason it opens activities in english !! i want to know why this strange behavior ?

the code to set language is :

```
 String languageToLoad = prefs.getString("language","ar");
    prefs.edit().putString("language", languageToLoad).apply();
    GlobalClass.language=languageToLoad;
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Log.d("configureLocale", "configureLocale: "+languageToLoad);
```

Comment: add your logcat output

Comment: i mean any crash , it doesn't belong to language , this behavior occurs after any crash of the application

Comment: Save the current language and when app is start load it to locale...

Comment: @Ebtehal___ Have you solved the issue??

Comment: no still not working

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code for changing language .Please implement this code as i have no issue in this.It will help you

```
        Locale myLocale = new Locale("language_code");
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```